# How to Increase the Image size in product listing page in opencart

Tags: php, opencart

How to Increase the Image size in product listing page in Open Cart?

Currently it outputs product images of the size 80 x 80, This is the default size.

How can we change the image size values for example say, I want to display 213x274 please help me.

Comment: This is not a programming question. Please ask opencart questions on http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/77558/opencart

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Login in to admin panel.
2. Go to `System > Settings` and click on edit button of your store.
3. Click on image tab.
4. Update the values of `Product Image List Size:`

That's it.

Have a nice day !!